# `dataRetrieval` misses historic data

Tags: r

Looking on the USGS site, data for gauge 10136500 are available back to "1919-07-01". However, when using the retrieval tool in R, data is only retrieved back to 1986.

Link to USGS page [USGS Gauge](https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/inventory?agency_code=USGS&site_no=10136500)

I realize that is says data availability begins in 1986, but the daily data for parameter "00060" are available back to 1919 and can be downloaded on the site if you follow the link.

```
library(dataRetrieval)

Gateway <- readNWISuv(siteNumbers = as.character(10136500),
                       parameterCd = "00060", 
                      startDate = "1919-07-01",
                      endDate = "2022-01-01")
```

Comment: I think you should let the [package author](https://github.com/DOI-USGS/dataRetrieval/issues) know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was user error. `readNWISuv` is for instantaneous values, but the older data is only available as daily values, which requires `readNWISdv`.

```
library(dataRetrieval)

Gateway <- readNWISdv(siteNumbers = as.character(10136500),
                      parameterCd = "00060", 
                      startDate = "1919-07-01",
                      endDate = "2022-01-01")
```